# Javascript optional key in an object

Tags: javascript

I have looked for an answer to this and Haven't quite been able to find it. Is it possible to have an object that includes/excludes keys dynamically?

Consider these two examples:

Example 1

```
const name = 'Garrett'
const city = 'Miami'

const obj = {
    name: name,
    city: city
}

console.log(obj) // { name: 'Garrett', city: 'Miami' }
```

Example 2

```
const name = 'Garrett'
const city = ''

const obj = {
    name: name,
    city?: city // Something like adding a "?"
}

console.log(obj) // { name: 'Garrett' }
```

If city is an empty string I don't want it to exist in the object at all. I understand that I can use a ternary, however in that case the key is still on the object just with a value of undefined, which I don't want. Sure I could check after creating the object, but that seems like a waste if there is a way of doing at the time of creation.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this isn't a duplicate, read the questions

Comment: I did, this does look like the same question being asked in the canonical

Comment: They're using jQuery. I'm asking about vanilla javascript

Comment: jQuery is not even tagged on the linked question. The top-scoring answer does not use any jQuery

Comment: The chosen answer says using jQuery that it would be doable

Comment: Look below it to the other answers. The accepted answer is often not the optimal answer.

Comment: I know I tried that approach before asking this question and it didn't work

Comment: `...(this.state.tmpUser.password !== '' && {password: this.state.tmpUser.password})`

Comment: That needs to be inside an object literal, like the top answer on the linked question shows

Comment: so this: `{ a: 1, b: 2, ...(this.state.tmpUser.password !== '' && {password: this.state.tmpUser.password}) }`

Comment: Yes, that code works

Comment: That's what I tried, just with different things for a and b and it doesn't work

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/wca5ypg0/

Comment: Ok that's fair. Thanks